# Visual studio publish button disabled?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-publish

I created a Node.js project in visual studio and I now wanted to publish it to azure, so I followed the following guide:
https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/wiki/Publish-to-Azure-Website-using-Web-Deploy#converting-to-an-azure-project-type

But the publish button when I right click on the project or the build menu at the top, the button is disabled. Any ideas?

[image: Publish button disabled]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you were trying to publish your website **while still in debug mode**. when you're in Debug mode some menu options could be disabled.

Verify that you aren't running Visual Studio Debug mode , I mean stop DEBUG, and verify again the publish option-.

[image]

Comment: This is unfortunately not the case.

Comment: My issue was solved using this.. Make sure you are out from the Debug mode into the Release mode. Then the publish option will be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this functionality is not available /no longer available for node project templates. However, if you are using Azure for hosting, deployment can still be performed using the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/get-started-with-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest). If you are using Azure functions like me, you may use the [az functionapp deployment source config-zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/deployment/source?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-deployment-source-config-zip) command to deploy a node function.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible that the option is greyed out because there is no specified location where to publish. To set the Publish Location, go to the Solution Explorer and click on the project name (not the solution name) and on the top right select the wrench icon ("Properties"):

[image: properties icon]

The properties window will open, which has 4 vertical tabs: General, Debug, Publish, and Test. Click on Publish and enter the Publish location. Don't forget to save your changes.
[image]